# Android Calculator Bug

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I coded a calculator for Android, but when I press the "equals" button while the app is running in the emulator, an error comes in the LogCat and the app closes.

Please help me fix the error.

Here's the LogCat Output:

```
07-25 01:34:13.213: I/Choreographer(1387): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 01:34:13.473: D/gralloc_goldfish(1387): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-25 01:34:50.653: I/Choreographer(1387): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 01:34:52.973: D/AndroidRuntime(1387): Shutting down VM
07-25 01:34:52.973: W/dalvikvm(1387): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab0ba8)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): Process: com.example.owncode, PID: 1387
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method Sum(View) in the activity class com.example.owncode.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button_calculate'
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Sum [class android.view.View]
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
07-25 01:34:53.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1387):     ... 11 more
07-25 01:36:28.423: I/Choreographer(1452): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 01:36:28.753: D/gralloc_goldfish(1452): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-25 01:36:32.873: I/Choreographer(1452): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 01:36:35.713: W/ResourceType(1452): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000009
07-25 01:36:35.723: D/AndroidRuntime(1452): Shutting down VM
07-25 01:36:35.723: W/dalvikvm(1452): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab0ba8)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): Process: com.example.owncode, PID: 1452
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     ... 11 more
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     at com.example.owncode.MainActivity.Sum(MainActivity.java:113)
07-25 01:36:36.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1452):     ... 14 more
07-25 01:39:31.103: I/Choreographer(1502): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 01:39:31.383: D/gralloc_goldfish(1502): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
07-25 01:39:35.203: I/Choreographer(1502): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-25 01:39:38.363: W/ResourceType(1502): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000009
07-25 01:39:38.423: D/AndroidRuntime(1502): Shutting down VM
07-25 01:39:38.423: W/dalvikvm(1502): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3ab0ba8)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): Process: com.example.owncode, PID: 1502
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     ... 11 more
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     at com.example.owncode.MainActivity.Sum(MainActivity.java:113)
07-25 01:39:38.603: E/AndroidRuntime(1502):     ... 14 more
```

Here's my MainActivity.JAVA:

```
package com.example.owncode;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText calculatorText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        calculatorText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.calculatorText);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        /*getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);*/
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.button_quitProgram) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void button_one_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("1");
    }

    public void button_two_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("2");
    }
    public void button_three_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("3");
    }
    public void button_four_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("4");
    }
    public void button_five_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("5");
    }
    public void button_six_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("6");
    }
    public void button_seven_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("7");
    }
    public void button_eight_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("8");
    }
    public void button_nine_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("9");
    }
    public void button_zero_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("0");
    }
    public void button_plus_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("+");
    }
    public void button_minus_click(View view){
        calculatorText.append("-");
    }
    public void button_backspace_click(View view){
        if (calculatorText.length()>0){
            String calculatorText_text = calculatorText.getText().toString();
            calculatorText_text = calculatorText_text.substring(0, calculatorText_text.length()-1);
            calculatorText.setText(calculatorText_text);
        }
    }

    public void Sum(View view){
        String str = calculatorText.getText().toString();
        int len = str.length();
        int i=0;
        String str1 = "", str2 = "";
        char op;
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, res=0;
        for(i=0; i<len; i++){
            if(str.charAt(i)=='+' || str.charAt(i)=='-')
                break;
            str1 = str1 + str.charAt(i);
        }
        op = str.charAt(i);
        i++;

        while(i<len){
            str2 = str2 + str.charAt(i);
            i++;
        }
        num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
        num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
        if(op=='+')
            res = num1+num2;
        else if(op=='-')
            res = num1-num2;
        calculatorText.setText(res);
    }

}
```

And, here's my main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_minus"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_minus"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:hint="@string/button_plus"
    android:onClick="button_plus_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_zero"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_plus"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_plus"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_plus"
    android:hint="@string/button_zero"
    android:onClick="button_zero_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_minus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="135dp"
    android:hint="@string/button_minus"
    android:onClick="button_minus_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_nine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_minus"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_minus"
    android:hint="@string/button_nine"
    android:onClick="button_nine_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_eight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_zero"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_minus"
    android:hint="@string/button_eight"
    android:onClick="button_eight_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_seven"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_eight"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_eight"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_eight"
    android:hint="@string/button_seven"
    android:onClick="button_seven_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_six"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_nine"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_eight"
    android:hint="@string/button_six"
    android:onClick="button_six_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_five"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_six"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_six"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_seven"
    android:hint="@string/button_five"
    android:onClick="button_five_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_four"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_five"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_five"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_five"
    android:hint="@string/button_four"
    android:onClick="button_four_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_six"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_five"
    android:hint="@string/button_three"
    android:onClick="button_three_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_three"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_three"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_four"
    android:hint="@string/button_two"
    android:onClick="button_two_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_two"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_two"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_two"
    android:hint="@string/button_one"
    android:onClick="button_one_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_backspace"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_three"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calculatorText"
    android:hint="@string/button_backspace"
    android:onClick="button_backspace_click" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_calculate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_backspace"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_backspace"
    android:hint="@string/button_calculate"
    android:onClick="Sum" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/calculatorText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_backspace"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:editable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/calculatorText_text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know it's all simple code but this is my first app and please help me so that I can get it running on a few of my relatives' devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this line you are getting error

```
calculatorText.setText(res);
```

change it into

```
calculatorText.setText(""+res);
```

You are setting `Integer` value..so View taken it as a `Resouce ID`.

Comment: Can you also suggest a way for re-coding Sum()?

Comment: @user2863992  If the solution is working please accept the answer. It will be helpful for others not to spend time on this.

Answer (score 1):

Change `calculatorText.setText(res);` to `calculatorText.setText(Integer.toString(res));`
You cannot set an integer value to an EditText.

Comment: Can you also suggest a way for re-coding Sum()?

Comment: seems to me that your sum() is ok.Are you encountering some exception?

Comment: No, it's working fine. But I just wanted to shorten it a bit more.

Comment: By the way, thank you very much! Your answer was the one which I understood and it was simple.

Comment: oh..thankx...I guess your code is okay.Still you can consult this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532668/calculator-with-one-input-edittext-android